# ImportError: No module named gevent

Tags: python, postgresql

I am new to the Python application development in Ubuntu.

I would try to be concise but please forgive and ask me if my explanations are too unclear to understand. I would be appreciated for your answers.

1. I have created a virtual environment for a project using  "virtualenv" command called cyoa.
2. PostGres DB is installed and I have created username and password to connect to the database.
3. The environment variable is  like follow:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export DEBUG=False
   export SECRET_KEY='supersecretproductionkeyforapp'
   export DATABASE_URL='postgres://username:password@localhost/cyoa'

   # Redis settings
   export REDIS_SERVER='localhost'
   export REDIS_PORT='6379'
   export REDIS_DB='1'

   # Twilio settings

   export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=''
   export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=''
   export TWILIO_NUMBER=''

   # Celery

   export CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379/0'
   export CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379/0'
   ```
4. When I activate the virtual environment and try to run the following script

   ```
   (cyoa)$ python manage.py syncdb
   ```

First lines of the manage script (which error is related to):

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import os
import redis
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 1, in <module>
from gevent import monkey
ImportError: No module named gevent
```

gevent final version is installed using the command:

```
sudo pip install gevent
```

Why I am reciving this error?

Comment: Have you installed the script in the virtualenv as well?

Comment: Don't use `sudo pip` inside a virtual environment. Just activate the virtual environment and use `pip install gevent`

Comment: Thanks Grooveplex and Timo I have used only pip in the virtual environment and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to install `gevent` using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python-gevent python-gevent-websocket
```

It will install `python-gevent` and `python-gevent-websocket` packages with dependencies `python-gevent-dbg` and documentation `python-gevent-doc`.